# Tap-to-click gone after suspend/resume

Tags: kde, touchpad

When I resumed my laptop this morning tap-to-click did not work.

It is also gone from my settings:

[image: tap-to-click gone]

I have tried clicking "[] Device enabled" to disable the touchpad completely and enabling it again. No luck.

Suspend/resume does not fix it.

`dmesg` has these now and then, but do not seem to affect normal use:

```
[176521.850445] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[176521.863190] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
```

I can reboot the machine (that is known to work); but is there another option?